# Protobuf Message With Arbitrary Type (.NET)

Tags: .net, protocol-buffers, grpc

I want to send/receive values with arbitrary types. At first, I thought the [`Any`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#any) type would allow types such as `string` `int32` etc. but it seems that the type must implement `IMessage` to pack or unpack it.

Is there a way to convert a `string` to an `Any` and vice versa?

If not, is there some other way to allow arbitrary types in messages?

E.g.

```proto
syntax = "proto3";

import "google/protobuf/any.proto";

package Engine;

message SomeMessage {
    string Id = 1;
    google.protobuf.Any AttributeValue = 2;
}
```

This code gives a compilation error in C#.

```cs
var someMessage = new SomeMessage
{
    Id = "123",
    AttributeValue = Any.Pack("Test")
};
```

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'Google.Protobuf.IMessage'

Answer (score 4):

It looks as though the answer may be the [`Value`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/google.protobuf#google.protobuf.Value) type.

```proto
syntax = "proto3";

import "google/protobuf/struct.proto";

package Engine;

message SomeMessage {
    string Id = 1;
    google.protobuf.Value AttributeValue = 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Packing a string in an Any type:

```
var someMessage = new SomeMessage
{
    Id = "123",
    AttributeValue = Any.Pack(new StringValue { Value = "foo bar"})
};
```

Unpacking the string:

```
var data = pack.Unpack<StringValue>();
doSomething(data.Value);
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?